# Go Through All The Rows of DataList Control on Button Click

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms, datalist

I need to check every row of a datalist on a button click to check if the checkbox inside the each row is checked or not. I put my buttons inside the FooterTemplate of the DataList but I couldn't find a way yet. This is my ItemCommand method;

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) {

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer) {

        if (e.CommandName == "AddContinue") {


        } else if (e.CommandName == "SkipContinue") {


        }

    }

}
```

here is my footer;

```
<FooterTemplate>

    <div class="top-margin-25">

        <div class="left-floathy">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPreviousStep"  Text="<<< Previous Page" 
                class="blueButtonSmall boxShadow" onclick="btnPreviousStep_Click" />
        </div>

        <div class="right-floathy">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddContinue" Text="Add & Contuniue >>>" 
                class="blueButtonSmall boxShadow" CommandName="AddContinue" /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="clarFix"></div>

        <div class="right-floathy">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSkipContinue" Text="Skip & Continue >>>" 
                class="blueButtonSmall boxShadow" CommandName="SkipContinue" />
        </div>

        <div class="clarFix"></div>

    </div>

</FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently I was a little careless for not seeing `DataList.Items` thing. Answer is sitting here;

http://blog.ysatech.com/post/2011/06/03/ASPNET-Get-selected-checkbox-value-in-DataList.aspx

**EDIT**

For others who has the same problem, here is the code;

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer) {

            if (e.CommandName == "AddContinue") {

                foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items) {

                    CheckBox extraCheck
                        = item.FindControl("extraCheck") as CheckBox;

                    if (extraCheck != null) {

                        if (extraCheck.Checked) {
                            Response.Write(item.ItemIndex);
                        }
                    }

                }

            } else if (e.CommandName == "SkipContinue") {


            }

        }

    }
```